# Build/Test monitoring tool over teamcity

Tags: rest, plugins, teamcity

This is my first team city based tool development project. I want to develop Java based web tool for reporting and monitoring of our build/test jobs running on teamcity.
Can you suggest any teamcity plugins which I can use for this development, I was planning to use springboot based framework and use team city rest api to query teamcity server. Having said that I keep hearing there are plugins available for writing such tools. Any pointers and suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recomment do not write the REST operations by yourself. Just use the [teamcity-rest-client](https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-rest-client)